# Ionic Dragula, setOptions mirrorContainer is null. Loading before DOM

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, dragula

I have an ionic project that is using dragula, but I'm having an issue setting the `mirrorContainer`.  I'd like to make the container something other than the default `body` because I believe that's what is attributing to a strange scrolling problem I'm having while dragging.

I've created my `bag` in html

```
<div class="step-container--line" [dragula]='"bag"' id="mirror">
    <div class="card">
    ....
</div>
```

Then in the JS, I've initialized dragula in the constructor and started to set its options.

```
constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
    dragulaService.setOptions('bag', {
      moves: function (el, container, handle) {
        return handle.className === 'step__menu__button';
      },
      direction: 'vertical',
      //mirrorContainer: document.getElementById('mirror')
    });
    dragulaService.drag.subscribe((value) => {
      this.onDrag(value.slice(1));
    });
    dragulaService.drop.subscribe((value) => {
      this.onDrop(value.slice(1));
    });
}
```

The problem is; when I add `mirrorContainer: document.getElementById('mirror')` to the `setOptions`, my mirror container comes back as `null`.  I'm assuming because this loads before the DOM does and there's no instance of `#mirror` yet.

If I moved everything down into `ionViewDidLoad(){}`, I get an error stating that `the bag 'bag' already exists`.

I'm not sure the best way to initialize or add to the options after the DOM loads.  Any ideas?

Comment: For anyone looking for somewhat of an answer, I wrote up a post here: http://cleanercoding.com/ionic-2-and-dragula-issue-with-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but I had the same issue using Angular 11.

After your element is in the DOM and is available you can do this.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    (this.dragulaService as any).groups['bag'].options.mirrorContainer = document.getElementById('mirror');
}
```